# How do I pass a variable into a URL in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, url, loops

How do I pass a variable into a URL in a Perl script? 
I am trying to pass the variables in an array to url. For some reason it is not working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The code roughly looks like this:

```
@coins = qw(Quarter Dime Nickel);

foreach (@coins) {
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST =>'https://url/$coins.com');
 }
```

This does not work as `$coins` does not switch to Quarter,Dime,Nickel respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To point you in the right direction: $coins != @coins in your example above.

Answer (score 7):

First, variables do not interpolate in single quoted strings:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "https://url/$coins.com");
```

Second, there is no variable `$coins` defined anywhere:

```
foreach my $coin (@coins) {
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "https://url/$coin.com");
 }
```

Also, make sure to use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

You should also invest some time into learning Perl properly.

Comment: Also, name the scalar value `$coin`, not `$coins`.

Comment: Or without having a loop variable, you may use `$coin[n]` or `$_` in place of `$coin`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
'https://url/' . $_  . '.com'
```

Instead of your

```
'https://url/$coins.com'
```